# Rails google map change static to dynamic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

hopefully somebody can help me.
I'm doing a project in Rails and at the moment I have a static google map included that's linked to an address in the model using the geocoder gem. I've tried looking up videos to try and change it to a dynamic map and keep the way the map links to the model but I can't find a way.
At the moment my show page looks like this:

```
<div id="map">
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=700x400&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@post.latitude}%2C#{@post.longitude}" %>
</div>
```

All I want is to keep the same thing but change it to dynamic, I'm only starting out in this stuff so sorry if it's a stupid question.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing the model to an instance variable (for example `@model` and then getting the address with `@model.address`? I see you've already included interpolated values in the string there, so that should work, unless I've misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Going from static to dynamic is a big step, but not too difficult. You'll have to use the [the google map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and fiddle a bit with javascript.

Another option is to use [Gmap4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails), a gem that wraps this API and is easy to use. The documentation has some examples on haow to link a model to a map.